# Is it haram to eat/drink from someone who’s unrelated to you?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith, practical-islam, food

I know eating/sharing food isn’t haram, but I was wondering if it was haram if say someone who isn’t related to me were to drink from a bottle. Would It become haram for me to drink from that bottle because someone who isn’t related to me drank from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will become haram only if a kafir(heathen) person drinks from the bottle. But, you can wash the bottle and use it again.
Even if one touches a heathen with wet hands(e.g. shaking hands), they should wash their hands.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn’t sure but I just wanted a clarification!

Comment: No problem. Asking is half of wisdom

Comment: Please consider supporting your claims by evidences and check [answer].